# A few questions about my first quadcopter build

Tags: quadcopter, microcontroller, radio-control

I'm planning to order parts for my first quadcopter build and I had a few questions. [Here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jJsP1noISRmEyQZirJVCQK5455tRXtAwk2ZPOVDElxk/edit?usp=sharing) is my parts list. I'm crossing my fingers that they are all compatible, and I'm pretty sure they are. I have two questions:

1. Do I need a Power Distribution Board and if so, what does it do?
2. Where on my flight controller do I attach my radio receiver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your frame is about (530g + other parts' weight), you need to make sure that your 4 motors give you a combined thrust of at least 100 g more than, just to get off the ground and maneuver. Anything greater than that is good. ([Thrust Calculator](http://aeroquad.com/showthread.php?1048-Calculating-motor-thrust)).

You battery amps * burst C / constant C should be greater than the motor amp pull * 4.

Propellers look OK. Make sure their inner diameter matches motor shaft diameter, else buy adapters.

Motor controller board is also good.

Your radio receiver output should control the ALE, THR, ELE, RUD (Aileron, Thrust, Elevation, Rudder). Which means the radio receiver output (the CHx output pins) should be the input (the 4 above) of the controller board.

Comment: Where can I get the details about those equations you linked me to?

Comment: That was just a random google search that I linked. When I built mine I found out that there is a relation between the wattage (W), the rpms (kV) and the thrust generated by the motor (depending on the props).